# Using perl mime::entity for attaching files?

Tags: perl, mime-types

below shows how one can add a file to a email being built using mime::entity
my question is instead of specifying a path to file, is there a way to add it via a varible which contains the context of the file, ??

```
### Attachment #2: a GIF file:
$top->attach(Path        => "./docs/mime-sm.gif",
             Type        => "image/gif",
             Encoding    => "base64");
```

Comment: I assume you mean [MIME::Entity](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME::Entity). Perl is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You need to drop the `Path` parameter and instead use `Data`, e.g.

```
### Attachment #2: a GIF file:
$top->attach(Data        => $my_gif_contents,
             Type        => "image/gif",
             Encoding    => "base64");
```

`Data` is a little bit buried in the `MIME::Entity` documentation, I must admit! I only know it from using the same parameter in `MIME::Lite`.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you don't get any other/better answers, it'd be great if you could accept this one, if it solved your problem ;-) Thanks